# ActiveAdmin points to wrong to wrong column in select box (name="post[category_id]" should be name="post[cname])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I startet a project with two models (post and category) and installed then ActiveAdmin. Everythin is fine except with the select box for "Categories" in create new Post and the select box in filters "CATEGORY" (right sided column).

My model for category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
```

My model for post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My model for admin_user:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, 
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

app/admin/admin_user.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

app/admin/category.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
   permit_params :cname
end
```

app/admin/post.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
   permit_params :title, :body, :category_id, :user_id, :admin_user_id, :email
end
```

With the inspector tool from Chrome browser development tools I found in create new post what is taken from the database table:

```
<select name="post[category_id]" id="post_category_id"><option value=""></option>
<option value="4">#<Category:0x007f61b9658e08></option></select>
```

and there it says name="post[category_id]" and not name="post[cname]" as I think it should be to show the name of the category in the drop down list (select box). Instead in the drop down this is listed:
    #

If I create a post by selecting this confusing name, in the show page of the post, the category name is shown as

```
/admin/categories/4
```

It took me already two full days of try and error with ActiveAdmin Intallation, issues with devise version and ActiveAdmin version and trying to fix this. But now I have no ideas left for fixing it.

I already found some how to's for changing a label or what I thougt it would be. But what I'm looking for is how can I change, what ActiveAdmin shows in the pulldown menu? As I know an object will be found by ID but I want the category name to that ID shown in the pull down - NOT the ID. This I thin should be the default output but what I get is text like this "#" in the drop down.

If there are more than one categories it would look like this in the drop down:

```
_________________________________
|_______________________________▼|
 | #<Category:0x007fac18bb1540>  |
 | #<Category:0x007fac18bb0f00>  |
 | #<Category:0x007fac18bb1220>  |
 | #<Category:0x007fac18bb0be0>  |
 | #<Category:0x007fac18bb92f8>  |
 |_______________________________|
```

**What can I do to change from showing this**

```
'#<Category:...7fac18bb92f8>'
```

**to the *category name* in the Pulldown?**

Comment: You are looking at the problem wrong - what ActiveAdmin is doing is correct. When you want to setup an association via a form you pass around the id of the associated record. That way it just works - if you pass the name instead you would have to do a silly query like `Post.new({ category_id: Category.find(params[:post][:cname]).id })`.

Comment: Instead your question should be "How do I change the label for an associated record in ActiveAdmin?"

Comment: That I had in mind but what I found for changing labels was that I was not sure, that I not only chage the name of the key "category_id" into something new but the value would be the same as before.

Comment: This is my first time working with ActiveAdmin.

Comment: You still don't get it. You're not supposed to change the value. If you want the input to change what category is associated with a post you pass `post[category_id]` with the ID of the category - this is not just in ActiveAdmin but in Rails in general.

Comment: If you want to create nested records on the fly you would pass something like `post[category_attributes][cname]` but thats a completely different scenario.

Comment: I do get it but my description of what I thought was not correct. I wanted to say, that I found some how to's for changing a label or I thougt it would be renaming. But what I'm looking for was to do it like you said. by finding a category with the id how can I than show the category name instead of the id.

I thin it should not be the default output that I get text like this "#<Category:0x007f61b9658e08>" in the drop down. Instead by default it should show the category name which has the column name "cname".

Comment: I believe what you looking for is using the `member_label` option in formtastic. Or you could add a `def to_s; cname; end` method in `Category` (replace the `;` with line breaks).

Comment: i don#t use the formtastic. I only want to have a correct name listing in the pull down menu, which shoul be default bu isn't.

Comment: Yeah, well how is ActiveAdmin supposed to know that is supposed to use that column for the option text? I actually don't know ActiveAdmin that well but you should edit your question and maybe someone will come along that does.

Answer (score 0):

The Discussion above helped me with finding the right solution for the porblem. As I read das ActiveAdmin something like educated guesses when displaying objects ([Link to were I found it](http://www.sitepoint.com/easy-admin-interfaces-active-admin-rails/)). It looks for method keywords like ":display_name", ":full_name", ":name", ":username", ":login", ":title", ":email" or "to_s" but not like in my case for ":cname". All I had to do was to genreate  to-string key word in my model:

My model for category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts

    def to_s                       <-
      "#{cname}"                   <-----the solution
    end                            <-

end
```